# Sharepoint 2013 add css in a page layout

Tags: publishing-site, page-layout, css, cssregistration

I'm trying to add my custom CSS file in my sharepoint 2013 page layout. I add it with the link tag or with CSSRegistration and when the page is rendered, the css does not appear in the source.

Also I don't know where I have to add my css in my html page layout. I try in the AdditionnalPageHead and other place and that's not work.

In my master page, adding a CSS file works fine.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: make sure that you're using the updated page layout (eg: it's not unghosted / customized), add other content in your page layout to ensure you're using the latest one. You can even include your style definitions in the middle of the content (thus not within head). Dirty and not final but most browsers will consume it straight away.

Comment: Hi, I put other content in my page layout and I see it when the page is rendered. I don't know why my css link don't appear when I see the source code with F12. Something missin but I don't know what.

Comment: copy the content of your css registration / page layout in your question, we'll better help you

Comment: @Francois Verbeek : I try these two methods for including css with no success. Sharepoint 2013 page layout doesn't seem to like custom css file '...</xml><![endif]-->
<title>PageAccueil</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Accueil.css">
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Styles/Accueil.css" runat="server">
</SharePoint:CssRegistration>
</head>'

Comment: Your css link is wrong. The browser will not be able to find the accueil.css stylesheet. You need to provide a SPSite relative path (eg: /_layouts/YourSolution/_css/accueil.css if you deploy them to 14\Layouts or point to the Style Library if they are deployed at that location. Courage :)

Comment: @Francois Verbeek: This is what I do and it's work. Thanks.     <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
                       <!--MS:<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&#60;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Test/Styles/Accueil.css %&#62;"  runat="server">-->
                <!--ME:</SharePoint:CssRegistration>-->

Comment: EHorodyski's answer is the best way to accomplish this, i.e., ensure that your entries are added after the Publishing register keyword. Safest is to insert it after "End Edit Mode Panel Snippet" but before &lt;/asp:ContentPlaceHolder&gt; end tag of &lt;asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server"&gt; then, add &quot;ms-design-css-conversion='no'&quot;. Added benefit of doing it this way is allowing you to add this html design file to a source code control system. PS: I would have voted up but I am new and do not have enough points to do so.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: For future reference, this should be a comment on EHorodyski's answer.

Answer (score 24):

I know exactly what you're looking for. While a debate about proper `link` tag usage and CSS storage folders is always a fun topic, realize none of that is your issue here.

There are two components that allows you to add `<link>` tags to Page Layouts.

First, you need to find the following lines of code in the head of the Page Layout's HTML page:

```
<!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
<!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="Publishing" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
```

After those three lines you are free to add `<link>` tags, with the following caveat: use the `ms-design-css-conversion="no"` attribute within the `<link>` tag to "exclude the style sheet from theming". Sounds counter-intuitive, but those are Microsoft's words, not mine.

In the end, you should have a `<link>` tag that looks as follows:

```
<link href="MyPageLayout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ms-design-css-conversion="no" />
```

[More Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822368.aspx#WhereStyles)

Comment: The answer by DrFeelGood is the most practical. Upload the css through the UI and its effects are local to the site.

Comment: +1 this is very useful answer....

Answer (score 2):

I have a lot of success adding CSS to a page by using the Script Editor web part (Found in Media and Content).  Place the web part, edit it and copy your CSS link or the CSS itself and save the page. I have been using it to style some in-page controls for Excel Services Web Parts.

Answer (score 2):

If you only wanted to add a couple of style overrides you can also embed your styles directly within the PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead placeholder using the following syntax.

```
<!--MS:<style type="text/css" >-->

.mystyle1 {}

<!--ME:</style>-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you set incorrect URL to your css file. You can try to see url using debug mode of a browser (usually you can press F12 for that) and then you could try to open this link directly in a browser window to see if it is accesible.

Also you can take a look at [a conversation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2219/css-files-in-layouts-or-document-library) about different places to keep CSS files. Maybe you find it useful.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that my css link reference is does not appear when I check the source code with F12.

Answer (score 1):

Place your CSS file under the master page gallery with the SharePoint designer (_catalogs/masterpage)

On your master page file on the header zone call the CSS like the example bellow

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<%$SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/bindtuning.css%>" runat="server" after="SharepointCssFile" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put any inline CSS style and inline javascript code to a Page layout as you can do it for regular HTML page.

For example inline style is

```
<style>
...
</style>
```

and inline javascript is

```
<script>
...
</script>
```